# SQL Server top with ties for both top and bottom

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, query-optimization, paging

I'm looking for a more efficient way to implement my paging in sql server 2008.

I need to retrieve result set rows @from to @to, ordered by score value, but I also need to retrieve all rows immediately before and after @from and @to that match the score value of those specific @from and @to rows. For example this could be like either of the two following queries:

N.b., score values are not unique, are not indexed, and are not provided to the rest of the query in a pre-sorted form.

a) (actually, I don't think this first example is guaranteed to give the results I need, because I don't think the order by in the 2 subqueries is guaranteed to produce an identical ordering. But for the sake of understanding what I would like a query syntax to do, consider only for this example that the order-by in the subqueries are identical)

```
select *  
from (  
    select top (@to) * with ties  
    from result_set  
    order by score desc  
)  tt  
union  
select  
from (  
    select top (@to - @from + 1) * with ties  
    from (  
        select top (@to) *  
        result_set
        order by score desc  
    ) tt  
    order by score asc  
)  tt
order by score desc
```

or

b)

```
/*EDIT: nested the rank() window function and related where criteria one level deeper than
the count(*), as this gave me significant (25%) decrease in runtime with my data, and just  
kinda makes sense.*/  

select score  
from (  
    select  
        score,  
        myrank,  
        count(*) over (partition by score) frequency  
    from (
        select  
            score,  
            rank() over (order by score desc) myrank
        from result_set  
    ) tt
    where myrank <= @to
) tt  
where @from <= myrank + frequency - 1  
order by score desc
```

I get the results I need using syntax (b) in combination with the following test CTE:

```
with result_set (score) as (
    select 0.5 union all
    select 0.5 union all
    select 0.2 union all
    select 0.1 union all
    select 0.55 union all
    select 0.5 union all
    select 0.1
)
```

But the partitioned window function requires 2 nested loops and 3 lazy spool operators. Is there a more efficient syntax for this?

Here is the current actual execution plan:
[image]

Comment: my goal is to see if there's something that can be done that doesn't assume any indexing at all on the score values, any pre-sort of the score values, or any use of values from a previous execution of the query, e.g. I can't know what was the lowest score value from the last time the query was run.

Comment: ideally it seems that the execution of the window-function query would not necessarily require spools and joins. I imagine there might be a newer window function syntax in SQL Server 2012 that might just do the same thing a little bit better than my 2008 is yet doing. But I'd like to get there with what I have available for now in 2008 developer or enterprise edition.

Comment: I haven't looked at your question in any detail but that's the plan shape you always get for windowed aggregates. It is only one spool that appears in the plan three times. More details about the [Common Subexpression Spool](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2010/07/28/partitioning-and-the-common-subexpression-spool.aspx) here

Answer (score 0):

You could get the bottom value first. Then make a regular pagination with top ties, yet including values equals to bottom value:

```
DECLARE @pageSize int = @to - @from + 1

DECLARE @bottomValue <datatype> = 
(
     SELECT MIN(score)
     FROM 
     (
          SELECT TOP(@from) score
          FROM <TABLENAME>
          ORDER BY score DESC
     )
)

SET @from = @from - 1

SELECT TOP (@pageSize) * WITH TIES --TopTies
FROM <TABLENAME>
WHERE <COLUMN_ID> NOT IN
                (
                                SELECT TOP (@from) <COLUMN_ID>
                                FROM <TABLENAME>
                                ORDER BY score DESC
                )
ORDER BY score DESC

UNION

SELECT *
FROM <TABLENAME>
WHERE score = @bottomValue --BottomTies
```

The benefits of using this query is that for the first pages, you would get faster response times (less reads). The downside is that as the @from increases, the reads also increase. However, I consider that if you use a type of function like row_number or rank, all the table data has to be evaluated no matter if it is the first page or the last.

Another way, not sure if the most appropriate for your case, is sending the lastvalue to the sp:

```
--Parameter
@lastScore <datatype> = null


--Logic

SELECT TOP(@to) * WITH TIES
FROM [TABLENAME]
WHERE score < @lastScore OR @lastScore IS NULL -- opt1
--WHERE score <= @lastScore OR @lastScore IS NULL opt2
ORDER BY score DESC
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion. The code unfortunately does not return the correct results. E.g., the given query with window-functions, when used with (@from, @to) = (3, 6), and with the example result_set data, returns all three rows with score = 0.5, while the suggested query returns only 2 of those rows.

Comment: I like the critical thinking about window functions versus order by. For the current case, the result_set data is not presorted so that order by also needs to evaluate the entire set. I did try a test however using row_number, and a temp table with presorted data, and according to the actual execution plan both approaches seemed to access the same number of *actual* rows from the temp table, with the window-query yielding a larger *estimated* number of rows.

Comment: Using a @lastScore value is a nice idea but that's not an option to me at this point.

Comment: Hi @JMHicks, yeah I did not keep in mind that top would restrict the result set from including all values. I edited the answer adding a UNION instead of the where clause. Take a look at it! Regarding the not presorted data set, I was thinking more about an indexed column.